# Item in position "0" (key) isn't removed, why?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
    $arr = array(
    "0" => 30,
    "1" => 31,
    "2" => 32,
    "3" => 33
);

if ($key = array_search(30, $arr)) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Why, if `30` is a value on `$arr` is not removed from it? If you try any other value like `31` or `33` code works but with the first key it doesn't and I don't know why, any advice? What I'm missing here?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Comment: @j08691 And it should be a assignment!

Comment: @Rizier123 you're right should be a assigment so the comment is complete wrong

Comment: @ReynierPM - no, the comment is not completely wrong. Your code logic is. See Jorge Zuverza's answer below.

Comment: @j08691 yes, my bad I see it now where my problem is, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if ($key = array_search(30, $arr))` evaluates to 0.

0 is a falsy value.

Therefore you never enter the if statement

try:

```
$key = array_search(30, $arr);

if (FALSE !== $key) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

var_dump($arr)
```

Comment: Show my code your code give the same result (`false == 0 => true`). copy my answer for your answer isn't good comportement...

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
if (FALSE !== $key = array_search(30, $arr)) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
}

var_dump($arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the result of

```
$key = array_search(30, $arr)
```

Equals zero, which is equivelant to boolean false.

Answer (score -1):

```
$key = array_search(30, $arr)
```

evaluates to 0, which is falsey. In your `if` you tried to check whether the element is found. `array_search` returns `FALSE` if the element was not found, so your if should be:

```
if (($key = array_search(30, $arr)) !== FALSE) {
```

Note, that I have used the `!==` operator, which will be `TRUE` even if the evaluation is 0. It would be a mistake to use the `!=` operator here, which is true only if the evaluation is truey.

Comment: I think someone don't want to have competitor.